# Ruby - How to split a string before specific keywords

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a string to get the substring before specific keywords or characters occur. e.g. Suppose special characters are `+` and `&` and the word `"hello"`.

So the strings `"He says hello to her"` and `"ten + three"` and `"the dog & the cat"` should return:

`"He says"` and `"ten"` and `"the dog"`.

I had been using `s.split(/[+,&]/).first` but I can't figure out how to get the "hello" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?=\bhello\b|\+|&)
```

You can split by this and take the first component.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/43

Comment: hmm. I get "SyntaxError: unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
s.split(?=\bhello\b|\+|&)"

Comment: @JacksonCunningham use `delimiters`.`a.split(/(?=\bhello\b|\+|&)/)`

Comment: sorry.. "SyntaxError: (eval):2: target of repeat operator is not specified: /?=\bhello\b|\+|&/"

Comment: What about just string.split(/ hello| +| & /)

Comment: @JacksonCunningham dont remove the `()`. `/(?=\bhello\b|\+|&)/`

Comment: Cute, but there's no reason for `\b`'s or lookaround. Think about it.

Comment: @pguardiario Lookahead may be but \b is required ...or it would break on hellob or bhello

Comment: Right but those are certainly silly cases to consider. Bhello?

Comment: @pguardiario Hahhaha English is strange u know :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use your original approach by removing the square brackets and escaping the `+`:

`my_string.split(/hello|&|\+/).first`

Answer (score 0):

```
str[/(.*?)\s*(hello|\+|&)/]
puts $1, $2
```